# Firebase Remote Config: user in randome percentile. Are users assigned only once?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Suppose I create a parameter with conditions such that users in random percentile < 10% will be assigned a certain value. The client fetches this value parameter and gets this value with 10% probability, if not it gets the default value. Next session the client fetches the same parameter. Will he get the same value again? Do users stay in the same percentile indefinitely or is a dice thrown each time they fetch the parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#rule_types):

> Each app instance is consistently mapped to a random whole or fractional number within a project, so you can use a rule of this type to consistently address the same app instances.
>
> For example, to create two related conditions that each apply to a non-overlapping .05% of an app's user base, you could have one condition include a <= .05% rule, and another condition include both a > .05% rule and a <= .10% rule.

So they receive the same value consistently.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking exactly for that.